# With how much $\sigma$ was Quantum Mechanics (QM) proven over Local Hidden Variable Theories (LHV) in experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

My question is how "sure" experiments are that QM is the right theory over LHV. I heard that the last bell inequality experiment came to the conclusion that QM was right with a certainty of $16\sigma$, but I could not find a source. Does anybody know the exact number or has a source with this number? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It seems that LHV type of theories can still be fine if statistical independence is not valid. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353970705_Supermeasured_Violating_Statistical_Independence_without_violating_statistical_independence

Answer (score 1):

For a comprehensive list, I guess just visit Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test

Apparently, the MPQ and LMU found up to $6\sigma$ confidence with $P \approx 10^{-9}$ that the results could be described by local hidden variable theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04604

Regarding the $16\sigma$, I don't know which source possibly Cirac was referring to...